# Manage buckets on amazon s3 on web app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket, buckets

I wonder on how to manage to the best way the structure between buckets and my application.

On my website there are few of uploader images for different script, example for `albums` or `profile picture` or `time line pictures`

**1)** do you think is better have 3 different buckets **one each** typology of picture example:

> - bucketmyprofilepicutres
> - bucketmyalbumpictures
> - buckettimelinepictures

or is better have only 1 bucket for all the pictures?

**2)** How do you structure your buckets thought to your application? there are any criteria for have a better structure?

Answer (score 1):

The most important reasons you would use different buckets are authorization and cost management. If you app is going to manage that, you can use a single bucket for everything. If you have, for example, multiple customers and you want to authorize and bill per customer (or other criteria), separate buckets may help. In this case, pick you bucket separation criteria thoughtfully, as you can have only 100 buckets per aws account.

Then, in the example as i understood, i believe that one bucket is a better approach. Always consider your case specifics and, when you have a more specific question, come again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, it is clear, I should not have criteria to set permission for the images thought if it belongs to albums or profile pictures doesn't matter. I just would like here other opinion before accept your answer. :)